# Install wxpython in python 3.4.2 windows 64 bit

Tags: wxpython

When I am trying to install wxpython in python 3.4.2 windows 64 bit. I am getting error as:

Command line :

```
C:\Users\praveen>pip install -U --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Error :

> Collecting wxPython-Phoenix
>   The repository located at wxpython.org is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host wxpython.org'.
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wxPython-Phoenix (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for wxPython-Phoenix

Comment: There was new activity in the wxPython wiki, should also work on Python3/64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Actually there is now a [working description on the wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip). The key is the `--trusted-host` argument. For reference the full command is added:

```
pip install -U --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Tested on Python 2.7.10 32 bit with most current pip/setuptools (which is another key to success here).

Comment: Tested and working on Win 8.1, Python 3.4.3 64-bit (Anaconda)

Comment: From https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/README.txt, the tag `wxPython_Phoenix` at the very end of the command line has been changed to `wxPython`. Also, wxpython's website is now accessible via `https` so you don't need the `--trusted-host wxpython.org` part anymore.